# Identify this tuber like object found on beach

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

Can anyone identify this tuber-like object I found on a beach in South Wales, UK? It's about 25 cm long and looks like a deflated football. Pretty spongy, saturated with water. I was hoping it was ambergris, but that seems unlikely.

[image]

[image: cross section]

Comment: Mabye it is a carcass or sea sponge or a rooton object. i am only nine!!!

Comment: Hi @EthanXiao. Welcome to Bio. We are a scientific stack and request answers to be backed up by scientific sources. Our target are people with a level of education matching that of a bachelor's or master's, and folks above that. Say 18+ years. Perhaps wait a few years before answering any other questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is spongy because it is a sponge, specifically a sea sponge. There are quite a large number of them native to the waters around england. I would guess *Craniella cranium* based on shape and location but I am by no means an expert on sponges. 
Here  a cross section of a cleaned sponge 
[image]

and sediment laden potato sponges after a hurricane.

[image]

you can see more images of collecting these here, http://www.vims.edu/newsandevents/topstories/archives/2011/irene_blobs.php

Here is a whole website dedicated to english sea sponges, http://www.aphotomarine.com/sponge_suberites_ficus_sea_orange_sulphur.html